Can I do a POST/PUT REQUEST to add/update the Shopify Search & Discovery app Related products and Complementary products?
Is it possible to do a POST/PUT request to add/update the Shopify Search & Discovery app Related products and Complementary products?
Related link:
https://shopify.dev/docs/storefronts/themes/product-merchandising/recommendations
I would like to have detailed instructions and example code to do this.

To add/update Related Products or Complementary Products for a Shopify store use the Search & Discovery app, you can manage these settings manually through the app, as Shopify does not provide direct API access for adding or updating product recommendations programmatically.

Managing these settings through the app as you mention is only possible for each product separately right? As I understand there is no bulk import of recommendations from a CSV file or similar.
This makes it not manageable for practical purposes.
